# how can i fetch table records through joins?

Tags: mysql

lets suppose I have database table X_tush where in there is column license,so for each license say 123 i have n number of columns associated to it,say address_id,status,address_type,etc.
for each license I have n number of networks say (101,102,108,113,114)
so for 123 license there exist a 3 records for 101,102,114 and 2 records for 108,113.
could you please help to replicate the records that exist for 101,102,114 for 113,108,as there are only 2 records associated to it?

```
select * from xpna;
```

-- get all the networks needed

```
select distinct network from x_pns_address where network in    (101,102,113,114,108
```

) into temp aln;

-- Identify all license with lest than 5 network

```
SELECT license,address_type ,contact ,address_line1,address_line2,city  FROM xpna WHERE network IN (101,102,108,113,114) GROUP BY license,address_type ,contact ,address_line1,address_line2,city  HAVING COUNT(network) < 5 into temp msn;

select * from msn,aln into temp table1;
```

-- Insert missing values in Temp table

```
INSERT INTO xpna
SELECT n.license, n.network, n.address_type , n.contact ,    n.address_line1, n.address_line2, n.city   FROM table1 as n 
LEFT  JOIN  x_pns_address  x
on x.network = n.network and x.license = n.license
group by x.address_type
where x.license is null;

select * from xpna;
```

Comment: post some of the code you have already tried...

Comment: see if you can relate now?

Comment: Can you tell the different tables, columns and values again as some kind of table (hard to follow when they are in sentences)? Also an example of your expected output.

Comment: address_type ,contact ,address_line1,address_line2,city these are the columns, table is xpna in the code i mentioned,

my expected output would be 3 records for each of the following networks 101,102,108,113,114.